# Cannot Display Data from MySQL in flutter Apps

Tags: mysql, flutter

#ASK Hello guys, I wanna display data from my database (MySQL) but when I run or debug on my Handphone, the data cannot display, and I didn't get any error. I am confused. Help me please. You can see my code on this picture.

[image]

[code screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nHWU.png)

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge:

It have to be your local network address and keep remember to plugin cable and run the app. Without USB connection and using a APK will not work when you try using local network URL. Best way to place your PHP code to a server. Here is free one with limitation: https://www.000webhost.com/free-domain-hosting